# Start certain command line tool always minimized

Tags: command-line

I am using Spyder as a Python IDE which calls an external compiler (NVCC) while running. This compiler opens in an external command line window.

Is there a way to create a batch-file or something similar that I can put in-between that relays all commands to and from the nvcc.exe but starts the process in the background? The nvcc is called hardcoded with extension (so I cannot use .bat)

I already tried setting a symbolic link to a .lnk that is set to 'minimzed' but that did not work.

Comment: You already answered your own question: `The nvcc is called hardcoded with extension (so I cannot use .bat)` if it's a hard coded call, how to you expect to change it?

Comment: @Seth Maybe there is a way to use an intermediate executable?

Comment: You said it's hardcoded so how would you expect to do that? You could replace the NVCC executable but it's probably a really bad idea as you would need to "forward" any stuff you receive to the original application. You probably should check the applications settings whenever you can't somehow setup another way of execution or supply parameters in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there seems to be no easy solution but I found a workaround using the following Python code:

```
import win32gui
import win32com.client
import time
prev_hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
while True:
    toplist = []
    winlist = []
    hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    title =  win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if 'nvcc.exe' in title.lower():
        shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
        shell.SendKeys('%')
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(prev_hwnd)
        print('Minimized nvcc.exe')
    else:
        prev_hwnd = hwnd

    time.sleep(0.001)
```